# Div's scrollbar only works when div position is relative

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a div where I output text to it and it has an overflow scrollbar. The problem is that it only scrolls when the #display_console's position is relative. It needs to be absolute because otherwise it messes up the layout of the page by blocking the space where it's moved from.

From Javascript I use stage.appendChild(displayConsole); to add it to the page.

Here's the CSS, there's other elements of course but these are the ones in question:

```
#stage {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top:30px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #5c440d;
}

#display_console {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position:absolute;
  right: 2%;
  left: auto;
  width: 170px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Page]

The div on the right won't scroll. If I change the position to relative, the buttons on the left move down and it goes all wonky.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: There has to be something else at play here. Any chance we can see this in action?

Comment: Yes, throw this up in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Although it doesn't look like it at this stage, it's actually a fairly complex facebook app so I couldn't put it in JSFiddle.

Do you think maybe another element is overlapping the display_console div or something?

Comment: if you think something is overlapping put the z-index: 9999; and lets see what happens.

Comment: You're a legend, that works!